# Помогите разобраться с WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я делаю приложение для своего сайта. Столкнулся с проблемой открытия ссылок посредством WebView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   WebView webview;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   webView();
}

   private void webView(){
   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
   webview.loadUrl("http://some-site.com/1.php");
}

@Override public void onBackPressed() {
if(webview.canGoBack()) {
    webview.goBack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("some-site.com/1.php")) {
        return false;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
}
```

Суть проблемы : при открытии страницы например somesite.com приложение открывает ее внутри себя. Но как только я устанавливаю редирект на эту страницу, после открытия приложения, ссылка открывается в браузере.
Почему так происходит пока не разобрался, но в целом хочу чтобы все ссылки открывались в моем приложении.  Редирект устанавливается для перенаправления на мой бложек, во время проведения тех работ на сайте. В JAVA я новичок и пока не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: а вы хотите, чтобы всегда всё было внутри вашей webview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это поведение Вы задаёте в методе `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)`.
Если нужно абсолютно все ссылки открывать внутри - метод должен возвращать `false`

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    return false;
}
```

и всё, остальной код не нужен.
Более того в стандартной реализации `WebViewClient` сделано именно так. Поэтому метод вообще можно не переопределять (убрать), а если Вы не собираетесь больше ничего в клиенте кастомизировать, то и класс не нужен - используйте стандартный:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Имеется ввиду ваот так?? public class MyWebViewClietn extends WebViewClient{ @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) { return false; } }

Answer (score 0):

Я , когда то так делал:
И там снизу вложенным классом сразу немного переопределил метод для открытия сторонних ссылок в хром табс ( хотя возможно вам это и не понадобится )
Что бы не лагало на корчах добавил хэндлер. Код древний , я тогда еще начинал, так что просьба не ругать особо. Но он рабочий вполне и простой.

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment  {
private WebView webView;
private WebSettings webSettings;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private static final String URL = "http://some-site.com/1.php";

private void webViewGoBack() {
    webView.goBack();
}

private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:{
                webViewGoBack();
            }break;
        }
        return true;
    }

});



@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_news, container, false);

    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView_1);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);//отменяем зум

    if (getActivity() != null) {
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()
                .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); }


    webView.loadUrl(URL_FINANCE);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    //тут прячем прогрессбар
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient1() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //тут меняем прогресс бар и прячем его
            view.bringToFront();
        }
    });
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
        //нажатие назат
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && webView.canGoBack()) {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                return true;}
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
}

class MyWebViewClient1 extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("http://some-site.com/")) {
            // внутренние ссылки открываем в рамках нашего приложения
            view.loadUrl(url); // или return false; как в офф. док.
        } else {
            // внешние ссылки открываем в браузере ChromeTab
//но это вообще можно убрать если хром табс не нужны
            ChromeTabUtils.openUrl(getActivity(),url);
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
           // view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }return true;
    }
}
}
```

При желании, если ничего делать не надо  класс WebViewClient можно не переопределять, как написали выше а просто прописать

```
WebViewClient wcClient = new WebViewClient();
webview.setWebViewClient(wcClient);
```

и все)

Comment: Чем Ваш код отличается от кода в вопросе (в смысле поведения)?

Comment: Так то да, простг в нем написано оде и почему происходит редирект.

Comment: Написано, кстати, на русском, для новичка)))))  хорошего дня)